# Ajax & ASP.NET MVC : get data by ID without using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data in my DataTable by ID, the data row coming from SQL Server to my controller but I am confused: how to pass this data to my DataTable in view?

I am using this code - my model:

```
public class EmployeesModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter date")]
    public DateTime HiringDate { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
    public JsonResult GetEmpByID(int id)
    {

        List<EmployeesModel> employeeList = new List<EmployeesModel>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConn"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetEmpByID", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id; //Added Parameter

            conn.Open();

            // Get
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                EmployeesModel employee = new EmployeesModel();

                employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmployeeId"]);
                employee.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                employee.Gender = reader["Gender"].ToString();
                employee.Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"]);
                employee.Position = reader["Position"].ToString();
                employee.Office = reader["Office"].ToString();
                employee.HiringDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["HiringDate"]);
                employee.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Salary"]);

                employeeList.Add(employee);
            }
        }

        //return View(employeeList); Commented out
        //return RedirectToAction("GetEmpByID"); Commented out
        return Json(new { data = employeeList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view

```
@model IEnumerable<SQLWithoutEF.EmployeesModel>

<input type="text" id="tablename" />  //Here I enter Employee ID and below is button
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" class="btn btn-danger" id="IDbtn" onclick="GetByName($('#tablename').val())">Get Data By ID</asp:Button>

@*Data Table ==============*@
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" id="MyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeId)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Gender)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Position)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Office)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.HiringDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Salary)</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employee1 in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none">@employee1.EmployeeId</td>
                <td>@employee1.Name</td>
                <td>@employee1.Gender</td>
                <td>@employee1.Age</td>
                <td>@employee1.Position</td>
                <td>@employee1.Office</td>
                <td>
                    @if (employee1.HiringDate != null)
                    {
                        @employee1.HiringDate
                    }
                </td>
                <td>@employee1.Salary</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:button class="btn btn-info btn-xs updbtn1">UpdateEmp</asp:button> |
                    <asp:button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-name="@employee1.Name" id="deletebtn" onclick="deleteF(@employee1.EmployeeId)">DeleteEmp</asp:button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery / Ajax - here I need help:

```
function GetByName(id) {
    if (confirm("Are You Sure to Get " + id + " " + " ?")) {
        $('#MyTable tbody tr').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetEmpByID?id=' + id,
            //data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
            //contentType: application/json, charset: utf-8,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            bprocessing: true,
            success: function (data) {   // Till here data coming but it's not working further

                var items = '';
                $.each(data, function (item) {
                    debugger;
                    var rows = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < item.length[0]; i++) {
                        rows = "<tr><td>" + data + "</td>"
                            + '<td><asp:button class="btn btn-info btn-xs updbtn1">UpdateEmp</asp:button> | <asp:button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-name="@employee1.Name" id="deletebtn" onclick="deleteF(@employee1.EmployeeId)">DeleteEmp</asp:button></td>'
                        "</tr>";
                        $('#MyTable tbody').append(rows);
                    }
                })
            },
        }).catch(function (xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMeassage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
            alert('Error - ' + errorMeassage);
        })
    };
};
```

Here is the screenshot what output I am getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9QNh.png)

Kindly suggest how I can send data from my controller to my DataTable using Ajax?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the DevTools and see if there any error? From what I see in your code, looks like your API action returns the response with the body as an object with `data` array but not the body as array. Would be great if you can share the response received in JSON by attaching it to the question. I doubt you loop `data` which is an object which is incorrect. And are you sure is this `item.length[0]` correct?

Comment: `int EmployeeId` .... `.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.NVarChar)` What type does the stored proc take? Have you confirmed the stored proc works?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLakeman to point out this error. I changed my SqlDbType from NVarChar to Int. Now my StoredProcedure working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the controller API action,

```
return Json(new { data = employeeList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

It will return the response with body as an object with `data` property which contains the array, instead of the response is the array.

The response body would be as:

```
{
  data: [/* Employee List */]
}
```

In JavaScript part, to take the employee array

```js
var items = data.data;
```

The implementation in `success` callback should be:

```js
var items = data.data;
$.each(items, function (index, item) {
    debugger;
    var rows = '';

    rows = `<tr>
        <td style="display:none">${item.EmployeeId}</td>
        <td>${item.Name}</td>
        <td>${item.Gender}</td>
        <td>${item.Age}</td>
        <td>${item.Position}</td>
        <td>${item.Office}</td>
        <td>${item.HiringDate}
        </td>
        <td>${item.Salary}</td>
        <td><asp:button class="btn btn-info btn-xs updbtn1">UpdateEmp</asp:button> | <asp:button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-name="${item.Name}" id="deletebtn" onclick="deleteF(${item.EmployeeId}">DeleteEmp</asp:button></td>
    </tr>`;
    $('#MyTable tbody').append(rows);
})
```

**Note: You may use the string interpolation / [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which makes it easier to build the template string.**

> Demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun. Really Great. It solved my problem. The date was coming in Json format that also I converted to normal date format.